# show grid as autocomplete in yii framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I want to show a grid as autocomplete in yii framework. I have tried with combogrid http://combogrid.justmybit.com/default.php but is not working with the downloaded file. Please help.

I have created an extension and extended the CJuiInputWidget. So the code is

```
class ComboGridWidget extends CJuiInputWidget
{

    public $source=array();
    public $sourceUrl;


    public function run()
    {
        list($name,$id)=$this->resolveNameID();

        if(isset($this->htmlOptions['id']))
            $id=$this->htmlOptions['id'];
        else
            $this->htmlOptions['id']=$id;
        if(isset($this->htmlOptions['name']))
            $name=$this->htmlOptions['name'];

        if($this->hasModel())
            echo CHtml::activeTextField($this->model,$this->attribute,$this->htmlOptions);
        else
            echo CHtml::textField($name,$this->value,$this->htmlOptions);

        if($this->sourceUrl!==null)
            $this->options['source']=CHtml::normalizeUrl($this->sourceUrl);
        else
            $this->options['source']=$this->source;


        $options=CJavaScript::encode($this->options);
        $this->registerScripts();
        Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#'.$id,"jQuery('#{$id}').combogrid($options);");
    }



    protected function registerScripts()
    {

        $asseturl=Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathofAlias('ext.combogrid.assets'));

        $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
        //$cs->registerScriptFile($asseturl.'/resources/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
        $cs->registerScriptFile($asseturl.'/resources/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js');
        $cs->registerScriptFile($asseturl.'/resources/plugin/jquery.ui.combogrid-1.6.3.js');

        $cs->registerCssFile($asseturl.'/resources/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css');
        $cs->registerCssFile($asseturl.'/resources/css/smoothness/jquery.ui.combogrid.css');
    }

}
```

In the view file I am using

```
$this->widget('ext.combogrid.CombogridWidget',array(
    'name'=>'city1',
    'options'=>array(
        'minLength'=>'1',
         'url'=> 'server.php',
         'debug'=>true,
         'colModel'=> "[{'columnName':'id','width':'10','label':'id'}, {'columnName':'name','width':'60','label':'title'},{'columnName':'author','width':'30','label':'author'}]",
         'select'=> "function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#city1' ).val( ui.item.name );
            return false;
        }"  
    ),

));
```

I have commented the jquery-1.9.1.min.js registration because Yii is already loading a jquery file and in that case I am getting a list of undefined values. If I use this jquery-1.9.1.min.js file then I am not getting any output. It only shows the loading image. I have placed the server.php file inside the yii app directory, that is where the entry script of yii resides. Also I want to know how can I place the server.php within the extension directory and use it in jquery ?

Comment: what is not working.post your code and error

Comment: @naveengoyal I have posted the code.

Comment: Problem is with passing the 'colModel' option within the view file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Naveen pointed out we can't help you much without more detail.

As an alternative you could use the [select2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) extension, and use the `formatResults` method to format the data received as rows.

Further reading:

1. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/